# Applying a 2D convolution kernel to each channel in Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

I have a single 2D kernel of size [3,3], and a Tensor of size [B, 64, H, W].

My question is, how can I apply the same 2D kernel to each input channel? Should I reshape/repeat the kernel? I tried to repeat my kernel as follows:

```
kernel = kernel.repeat((B, 64, 1, 1))
```

But when I apply it the tensor size changes to [1, 64, H, 1].

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use grouped convolutions with one group per input channel.

Example using [`nn.functional.conv2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.functional.html?highlight=conv2d#torch.nn.functional.conv2d) directly

```py
# suppose kernel.shape == [3, 3] and x.shape == [B, 64, H, W]
weights = kernel[None, None, ...].repeat(64, 1, 1, 1)
y = nn.functional.conv2d(x, weights, groups=64)
```

or using [`nn.Conv2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=conv2d#torch.nn.Conv2d)

```py
conv = nn.Conv2d(64, 64, 3, groups=64, bias=False)
conv.weight.data = kernel[None, None, ...].repeat(64, 1, 1, 1)
y = conv(x)
```

Of course you could also specify any padding, stride, or dilation that you want by including those arguments.

Comment: This is perfect for the forward prop. During backprop each sub-kernel of the group gets it own gradient updates. But they are all actually supposed to be the same.

Comment: How can I fix this?

Comment: @SPSharan If you wrap the `nn.functional.conv2d` version in an `nn.Module` with `kernel` as an `nn.Parameter` then that should work with backprop the way you expect.

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I did to implement it.